# Count and get details of a comment post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

I'm an admin of a few facebook pages.
Every time I post a message as the admin (the page itself), I'd like to count the number of likes and comments on that post and, which user did so and save the data to my db.
Is it possible to do that?
Please notice that it's not the [comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), but the page posts.

Comment: To answer your question - yes. This is possible. Please read the [FAQ] and learn what types of questions you can ask here.  People will not do the work for you. Your question has to be more specific.

Comment: I don't expect people to do the work for me. I know it's possible with the comments tool and was wondering if it's possible also in this case when the post is a page post.
Thank you for letting me know it's possible, though I haven't seen any documentation for that.

Comment: There is no documentation for that specific action because it is exactly the same as retrieving information about any post.  The user requesting the information only has to have the right permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a HTTP Get `/me/feed` on the Graph API to get a list of feed items using a PAGE access token.

Each feed item will have `likes` property "*Structure containing a data object and the count of total likes, with data containing an array of objects, each with the name and Facebook id of the user who liked the post*"

Each feed item will also have a `comments` property "*Structure containing a data object containing an array of objects, each with the id, from, message, and created_time for each comment*"